# Can Jquery Mobile use Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to use http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Will it be possible with jquery mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but the method in my previous answer it doesn't really work because the tap is captured for the scrolling.

I found this wonderful library which makes the trick: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

And a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Basic Lists</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="sortable">
            <li><a href="index.html">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">BMW</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Cadillac</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Chrysler</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Dodge</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ferrari</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ford</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm afraid it won't work well for a long list on a small screen.